# How to define nested static directories in app.yaml?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have static directory "/static", with js and css files, and inside it another directory "images". How can I define this in app.yaml so that images are accessible from js and css files using relative directories? For example, in "/static/main.css":

```
.bck {background-image: url(images/img.png); }
```

Should refer to "/static/images/img.png".

The following doesn't work:

```
handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /static/images
  static_dir: static/images
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything. `/static` already includes `/static/images`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your app.yaml you need to define once a static directory like this.

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  expiration: "7d"
```

In your static directory you can create other directory for js or css or images and It's not necessary to redeclare theme.

To call you static files you need just to specify your static path like this: /static/images/xxxx.png

Comment: thanks! i had another issue in my code which caused the problem... fixed now :)

Comment: @olituks If from inside “static” directory, we don’t want to change the path to images like in the answer, in case the js and css files are created by other developers and we do not want to make changes to their files, what do we need to add to the app.yaml file to make it work?